# Hilbertify an image

Tags: code-golf, math, graphical-output, image-processing, fractal

I like the [Hilbert Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve).

---

Your task for this challenge is to take an image (strictly a square image where all the sides are a power of two pixels wide) and unravel it line by line in a zig-zagging fashion and ravel it back up in a pseudo-Hilbert curve.

### Unraveling

To unravel you will start with the pixel in the upper left hand corner and travel right until you arrive at the edge of the image.  Once you have hit the edge of the image you will move down to the next row and begin traveling left until you hit the edge again.  You will continue unraveling row by row switching the direction each time so you get one continuous curve.  This should look like a well played game of snake

The result of unraveling should be an order of pixels that includes every pixel exactly once

### Reraveling

Once you have an order for the pixels you will rearrange them on a new equally sized canvas following the path of a pseudo-Hilbert curve.  For a `2**n` sized square image you should use the nth iteration of the pseudo-hilbert curve.  Each pixel will be placed in exactly one spot on the new canvas.  You should reravel the image so that the point originally in the top left (the start of our snake curve) will remain there and point in the bottom right (the end of our snake curve) will be placed in the top right.

### I/O

Your program or function should take in an image of specified constraints via standard methods and output another image via standard methods.

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) program with the fewest bytes wins.

### Examples

#### Input

[image: Mondrian]

#### Output

[image: Output 1]

---

#### Input

[image: Rothko]

#### Output

[image: Output 2]

---

#### Input

[image: Scrambled]

#### Output

[image: Lion]

---

I also recommend testing on a blank white or solid color image to make sure you are not missing any pixels.

Feel free to include your own results in your answers!

Comment: Is it okay to take an array of RGB values instead of an image as the input? What about output?

Comment: @JHM No you cannot.  You can choose whatever image format you want though, so if your language doesn't have builtin image support you can use an uncompressed .ppm file which is very similar to an array of RGB values.

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica, <s>286</s> 273 bytes

```
Image[Array[1,{l=Length@#,l}]~ReplacePart~Thread[#&@@@Split[#&@@@FoldList[Switch[#2,"-",#{1,I},"+",#/{1,I},"F",#+{ReIm@Last@#,0},_,#]&,{{1,1},I},Characters@Nest[StringReplace@{"L"->"+RF-LFL-FR+","R"->"-LF+RFR+FL-"},"L",Log2@l]]]->Join@@MapAt[Reverse,#,2;;;;2]]]&@*ImageData
```

Phew! Challenging but fun!

## Explanation

```
ImageData
```

Convert an `Image` into an array of RGB values.

```
Array[1,{l=Length@#,l}]
```

Generate an `l` by `l` array with head `1`, where the `l` is the length of the input (i.e. the width of the image).

This yields `{{1[1, 1], 1[1, 2], ..., 1[1, L]}, {1[2, 1], ..., 1[2, L]}, ..., {1[L, 1], ..., 1[L, L]}}` (`l` written in caps to reduce confusion)

```
StringReplace@{"L"->"+RF-LFL-FR+","R"->"-LF+RFR+FL-"}
```

A `StringReplace` function that replaces every `"L"` with `"+RF-LFL-FR+"` and `"R"` with `"-LF+RFR+FL-"`

```
Nest[ ... ,"L",Log2@l]
```

Apply the `StringReplace` function to the `String` `"L"`, `Log2[l]` times.

```
Characters
```

Convert the resulting `String` into a `List` of characters.

```
Switch[#2,"-",#{1,I},"+",#/{1,I},"F",#+{ReIm@Last@#,0},_,#]&
```

An unnamed function that:

- If the second input is `"-"`, multiply the second element of the first input by `I`.
- If the second input is `"+"`, divide the second element of the first input by `I`.
- If the second input is `"F"`, increase the first input by the `ReIm` (separates the real and imaginary part of the input) of the second input.

```
FoldList[ ... ,{{1,1},I}, ... ]
```

Starting with `{{1,1},I}`, cumulatively apply the above unnamed function, using each element of the `List` of characters as the second input. This code yields the outputs of all iterations.

```
#&@@@Split[#&@@@ ... ]
```

Get rid of the second elements of each `List` and delete duplicates. (The steps up to this point generate a `List` of coordinates of the Hilbert curve)

```
Join@@MapAt[Reverse,#,2;;;;2]
```

Unravel the input RGB array (reverses every other row and flattens).

```
Thread[ ... -> ... ]
```

Create `Rule` objects, such that the first element in the first input (the coordinates of the Hilbert curve) is paired with the the first element of the second input (the unraveled image), the second element with the second input, and so on.

```
... ~ReplacePart~ ...
```

Apply those replacement `Rule`s to the `Array` from the second step.

```
Image
```

Convert to the array of RGB values into an `Image`.

## Sample in/out

Input:

[image: Test case 1]

Output:

[image: output]

---

Input:

[image: Edward and Alphonse Elric from Fullmetal Alchemist]

Output:

[image: wat]

## Inverse function (<s>266</s> 253 bytes)

```
Image[MapAt[Reverse,Extract[#,#&@@@Split[#&@@@FoldList[Switch[#2,"-",#{1,I},"+",#/{1,I},"F",#+{ReIm@Last@b,0},_,#]&,{{1,1},I},Characters@Nest[StringReplace@{"L"->"+RF-LFL-FR+","R"->"-LF+RFR+FL-"},"L",Log2[l=Length@#]]]]]~Partition~l,2;;;;2]]&@*ImageData
```

Answer (score 6):

## Octave 234 Bytes

```
I=imread(input(''));w=rows(I);X=[0,3;1,2];for k=2:log2(w);n=numel(X);X=[X',rot90(X',2)+3*n;X+n,X+2*n];end;for k = 1:3;I(2:2:end,:,k)=fliplr(I(2:2:end,:,k));end[~,S]=sort(X(:));I(S+(0:w^2:2*w^2))=permute(I,[2 1 3]);imwrite(I,input(''))
```

File names of input and output images should be provided form standard input.
size of code without input/output is **194 bytes**.
Explanation:

The base pattern of indices is:

```
X =
  0 3
  1 2
```

In each iteration 4 copies from result of the previous iteration made and some transformation applied to each copy then all blocks concatenated to form the current result.

```
X =[0,3;1,2];
for k = 2:log2(s)
    n=numel(X);
    X = [X',rot90(X',2)+3*n;X+n,X+2*n];
end
```

so we have:

```
block(1,1): X' 
block(1,2): rot90(X',2)+3*n 
block(2,1): X+n
block(2,2): X+2*n

0    1  | 14   15
3    2  | 13   12
--------|--------
4    7  |  8   11
5    6  |  9   10
```

Hilbert indices sorted and indexes of sorted elements returned:

```
[~,S]=sort(X(:));
```

Unraveling applied flipping all even rows:

```
for k = 1:3
    I(2:2:end,:,k) = fliplr(I(2:2:end,:,k));
end
```

Reraveling applied :
-S repeted for each channel
-permutation applied since in Octave data arranged column wise

```
I(S+(0:w^2:2*w^2))=permute(I,[2 1 3]);
```

Example images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can choose to have your program work as a function if you want to avoid using I/O.

Comment: function+end keywords consume more bytes!