# Hilbertize an image

Tags: code-golf, array, geometry, image-processing, fractal

For a computer vision app I want to do a mapping of an image, in such a way that every pixel fit [hilbert curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve), instead of conventional layout. So task could be as follows:

---

### Task description

Given square 2D image `A` with side `2^^N`, (`N>0`), with common Z-order, or row-major representation of pixels in RAM. I need to run a hilbert curve through this image (Like a digital camera, where photodiodes are soldered in a hilbert curve and numbered and accessed in a 1-d ordered manner). Then pixels along this curve just layed down as a regular scanline in image B. So now any consequent samples in output array B now should represent spatially close points in input array A.

---

### Example for `N=2`

[image: Example infographic]

```
Input: array A (imagination of 2D image)
0 1 E F  
3 2 D C     
4 7 8 B    
5 6 9 A 

Input: array A (1D actual layout in memory)
0 1 E F 3 2 D C 4 7 8 B 5 6 9 A

Output: array B (answer)
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F
```

Note, that values inside arrays are "values". In this example, for array B  accidentally they became same as indices. So basically I want index mapping function B[i]=A[?], e.g B[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdtBj.png) = A[E]. 
Hope code golfing helps.

---

### Example for N=9:

Taken popular 512*512 test image.
Each pixel was threated as 32bit integer, in RGBA format and algorithm proceeded:

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

---

### Reverse question:

Here is [reversed-task question on codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101871/hilbertify-an-image).

In terms of that question, I want to do opposite transform: "I want to *Reravel* image A, then *Unravel* to image B".
In terms of examples of that question: I want to take *photo the lion* on the camera with hilbert-curved-sensor (look *Output* array for lion photo) and get that long "scanline of spatially close pixels" (Input for lion photo, in that question)

---

### Reference implementation:

If i take `d2xy()` function [from LGPL sources found here](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/hilbert_curve/hilbert_curve.html) I may write a following program, which works, but maybe not its best way:

```
#include "hilbert_curve.h"
int main(){
  int *A,*B,i,x,y;
  for(i=0;i<(1<<(N<<1));++i){
    d2xy(N,i,&x,&y);
    B[i]=A[y*(1<<N)+x];
  }
}
```

---

### Resources:

- [Spatial indexing with Quadtrees and Hilbert Curves](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/11/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Spatial-indexing-with-Quadtrees-and-Hilbert-Curves)
- [`hilbert` function, which returns a rendering of Hilbert Curves](http://people.cs.aau.dk/~normark/prog3-03/html/notes/fu-intr-2_themes-hilbert-sec.html#fu-intr-2_hilbertprog_title_1)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/104392/58563).

Comment: @Arnauld Yes, i saw it previously. I don't need to copy few identical symbols with rotation, but different bytes or arbitary 2D image, to "hilbertize" it.

Comment: And BTW: welcome to PPCG! Although this site is dedicated to recreational programming challenges and not recommended for real world problems, this looks like a perfectly valid challenge nonetheless -- though it might currently be a bit under-specified.

Comment: So, what is the input and what is the output? One could e.g. assume an input of `N` and and a list of carthesian coordinates visited along the curve as ouptut? Also please see https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8078/71420

Comment: Also a word of warning, your text reads as if you're looking for an actual solution to **use** it. Nothing wrong with that, as long as it's a good challenge, but code-golf solutions tend to be more or less useless for realworld coding ;)

Comment: Welcome to ppcg and nice first challenge!  Unfortunately it has already been asked here.  Hope you stick around anyway!

Comment: @PostLeftGarfHunter Nope, this is NOT an answer, but a reverse task! I I need his OUTPUT, and to produce INPUT!

Comment: @PostLeftGarfHunter I probably made an error initially, i corrected it now.

Comment: You may want to provide another test case for \$N>2\$.

Comment: I would recommend adding a link to the Hilbert Curve wiki to the question, so that people may more easily read about it.

Comment: @xakepp35 Just to clarify my suggestion, the purpose of test cases is to check that a submitted program is working properly, not to help understand the challenge (although they may sometimes do -- but the challenge should not rely on that).

Comment: @KamilDrakari just did that, btw, ppl on this site usually have google as their best friend!

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 38 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
U1¦U;$;;UN$
Ll2’ð⁽Æ¬b3’s2Ç⁸¡⁵DW¤;+\Ḋœị
```

A monadic Link accepting a square matrix of side \$2^n\$, \$n\$ a positive integer which yields an array of the inputs elements in Hilbert curve order.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY@tTsRAFIX9PsWIdVTs/ZlhN7VIgmsQpYYEQ@pQOGqWBCQKSUJQCAzJJgTThgfZvsjwTcXJzT33nG/a25u@v8@5kfGjqdd13VysV@e9zg@v09c8/E778fPa2O50epyHw/g2D99nl@N7fXJ1PDz9vRx/nnPObRukCsFRRKkKcVeFtEH4ybtV1QblYmiLTkkwIzPhJysJoSuFQVfoRvZYWDDiZkmwCQyhI8UlHdkju@@WBESBbFwN17gaKcf3bUkoZOEFY2qZMI2XnOlxSdBVOoqrhVW6pB3fl39RyApZ6ShXKylYXr7Duu4f)**

#### How?

First we create `[row, column]` index deltas describing the U shape with an initial right move (i.e into the \$n=1\$ matrix's top-left corner from the left) - that is `[[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [-1, 0]]`.

Then we repeatedly perform a transform keeping the current list of deltas to describe the bottom-right quarter of the next and adding the other three quarters as copies with reversed deltas (swapping row changes with column ones where necessary and negating directions of the new top-right quarter).

Finally we prepend a starting index of `[1,0]` (to the left of the top-left of our [1-indexed] matrix), cumulatively reduce by addition to get the indexes, discard the `[1, 0]` and index into the input.

#### How?

```
U1¦U;$;;UN$ - Link 1, transform deltas to next size: list of current deltas
U1¦         - reverse the first delta (makes bottom-left)
   U;$      - reverse each of those and concatenate with that (adds top-left)
      ;     - concatenate with the input (adds bottom-right)
        UN$ - reverse each of the input deltas and negate (makes top-right)
       ;    - concatenate (adds top-right)

Ll2’ð⁽Æ¬b3’s2Ç⁸¡⁵DW¤;+\Ḋœị - Main Link: square matrix (of side 2^n), M
L                          - length of M
 l2                        - log base 2 (=n)
   ’                       - decrement
    ð                      - start a new dyadic chain (i.e. f(n-1, M)) 
     ⁽Æ¬                   - compressed literal = 4258
        b3                 - to base 3 = [1,2,2,1,1,2,0,1]
          ’                - decrement = [0,1,1,0,0,1,-1,0]
           s2              - split into twos = [[0,1],[1,0],[0,1],[-1,0]]
               ¡           - apply repeatedly...
              ⁸            - ...number of times: chain's left argument, n-1
             Ç             - ...what?: last Link as a monad
                           -           - gets all deltas
                   ¤       - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
                ⁵          -   literal ten
                 D         -   to decimal digits = [1,0]
                  W        -   wrap = [[1,0]]
                    ;      - concatenate with the deltas
                     +\    - cumulative reduce using addition (N.B. Ä wont work here) 
                       Ḋ   - dequeue (drop the [1, 0] leading index)
                        œị - multi-dimensional index into M
```

Comment: Whoa! Whole 38 bytes, even for jelly..

Comment: There could be a shorter way, and this way might be golfable.

Comment: Note also I restrict n as positive (i.e. no 1*1 input). I guess that's fine?

Comment: Sure, "1*1 conversion" is a trivia, which does not require even running code (output = input) and is no of interest. You may omit such check, will add this to conditions.

Comment: Fastest way of doing it (that I found up to day) is to build index lookup table `s2h[2^^(N*2)]` for given N, before batch-processing multiple same sized images. Then, just call `B[i] = A[s2h[i]]`, while processing each pixel. For N=9 lookup table will take whole 1MB (512*512*4), which is not quite friendly for L1/L2 CPU caches. Hopefully it will be at L3.. So (to be honest) I am looking for a indexing function `f(i) = s2h[i]`, which will be faster using math, that using single memory lookup. Memory-heavy algorithms are way slower than SSE/AVX, are ASIC-resistant and not very good even on GPUs!

Comment: fast != golfed :p

Comment: That implies restrictions: if I want to use it as 1D codec instead of 2D jpeg MDCT transform (MJPEG in most webcams) and embed it to robotics vision camera circuit (for "onboard compression") - I would also have been forced to add a (expensive) memory with indices LUT table to that camera circuit. Even its read-only, and can be pre-flashed once. Best way would be to solder matrix addressing bus in a form of hilbert curve, but that is a challenge about producing very specific CMOS sensor. ;-P

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what most of that means :)

Comment: No problem! Thanks for your effort, good solution! Lets wait for what others could offer..