# Multi-level marketing "legs" investment rule

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

Multi-level marketing related challenge.

A peer wants to get rewarded. So it attracted `N` investors (`N>=1`), each i-th investor invested `x[i]`. When a total sum exceeds threshold `x[0]+x[1]+...+x[N-1] >= T` a peer could be rewarded. But only if a following conditions are satisfied:

- Minimum amount of investors should be greater than `M`, (`M<=N`)
- For at least one integer `k`, where `k>=M` and `k<=N`, any `k` investors have to invest at least `T/k` each;

Given `N, x[], T, M` you should determine whether the peer's reward is generated or not (boolean result, "yes" or "no"). Shortest code wins.

**Examples:**

---

`N=5; M=3; T=10000`, in order to generate the peer's reward one of the following must be satisfied:

- any 3 invested at least 3334 each
- any 4 invested at least 2500 each
- all 5 invested at least 2000 each

---

`N=6; M=2; T=5000`:

- any 2 invested at least 2500 each
- any 3 invested at least 1667 each
- any 4 invested at least 1250 each
- any 5 invested at least 1000 each
- all 6 invested at least 834 each

---

generalized: for any `k`, where `k>=M` and `k<=N`:

- any `k` of `N` investors invested at least `T/k` each

---

**Test cases:**

*format:*

`N, x[], T, M -> correct answer`

```
6, [999, 999, 59, 0, 0, 0], 180, 3 -> 0
6, [0, 60, 0, 60, 60, 0], 180, 3 -> 1
6, [179, 89, 59, 44, 35, 29], 180, 3 -> 0
6, [179, 89, 59, 44, 35, 30], 180, 3 -> 1
6, [179, 89, 59, 44, 36, 29], 180, 3 -> 1
6, [179, 90, 59, 44, 35, 29], 180, 3 -> 0
6, [30, 30, 30, 30, 29, 30], 180, 3 -> 0
6, [30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30], 180, 3 -> 1
```

Comment: `N` is implied by `len(x)`, I suppose we can but do not *have* to take it as an input, right?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Sure, if your language allows it, and writing `len(x)` will be shorter than writing `N`. That is made, because for dynamically allocated array `x` in C there is no direct `len(x)` function - so you may always refer to length as `N`. For convenience, you may consider all input data `N, x[], T, M` as some externally defined constants, or some language built-ins.

Comment: @luis-mendo  It's unclear "what is exactly unclear?"

Comment: @erik-the-outgolfer Could you explain?

Comment: I don't think those notifications reached them (with the hyphens) as I got them in my inbox.

Comment: @JonathanAllan not quite familar with pinging syntax, and non-latin names.. maybe they will return some day :)

Comment: It might be worth adding some test cases ...including some at edges like: `6, [100, 50, 77, 22, 14, 44], 180, 3` -> `0`; and `6, [100, 50, 77, 22, 14, 45], 180, 3` -> `1`.

Comment: Does `M` have a minimum value? e.g. at least more than 0, or can it also be negative?

Comment: Can `M` be 0-indexed? (i.e., `2` in each of the test cases)

Comment: Also, can output be reversed? A falsey value for `true` and  truthy value for `false`?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance, I don't think it would be possible to have a negative number of investors! But the first part of your question *does* need answering; the current requirements that `M<=N>=1` do imply that `M` could be `0`.

Comment: Can't the second bullet point be more simply put as "Each investor must invest \$T/N\$"?  If there is any \$k\$ that fulfills the requirements it holds that \$k=N\$ fulfills the requirement and of course the converse is trivial.  Am I missing something?

Comment: There also doesn't seem to be a winning criterion?

Comment: @WîtWisarhd Code golf is a winning criterion... look at the tags.

Comment: @WitWisarhd Initially it was there, but was removed after a bit of thinking - it does distract away from real condition point, and it can be derived, (just check condition for a case k==N)

Comment: I noticed the example for `N=5; M=3; T=10000` allows for 3 investors with 3334. This implies that "integer division" (i.e. round down) wouldn't work. Was this intentional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>12</s>  9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṢṚ×J$ṫ⁵<Ṃ
```

A full program which accepts `x T M` and prints `0` if the peer is rewarded and `1` if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkUPd846PN1L5eHO1Y8at9o83Nn0////aENzSx0FCyA2BWITEx0FY1MdBSPL2P@GFgb/jQE)**

#### How?

```
ṢṚ×J$ṫ⁵<Ṃ - Main Link: list of numbers, x; number, T   e.g. [100, 50, 77, 22, 14, 45], 180
Ṣ         - sort x                                          [ 14, 22, 45, 50, 77,100]
 Ṛ        - reverse                                         [100, 77, 50, 45, 22, 14]
    $     - last two links as a monad:
   J      -   range of length                               [  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6]
  ×       -   multiply                                      [100,154,150,180,110, 84]
     ṫ    - tail from index:
      ⁵   -   5th argument (3rd input), M   (e.g. M=3)      [        150,180,110, 84]
       <  - less than T?                                    [          1,  0,  1,  1]
        Ṃ - minimum                                         0
```

Comment: seems not working: https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkWHp/uoHJ5wbMnDnasfNW61ebiz6dCah7sW/P//P9rQwEBHwdhYR8EISENR7H@g6H9jAA

Comment: in example third investor invested less than 1/3rd of T (less than 33), but result still counted as positive ("any k invested at least T/k each" failed)

Comment: Yeah, I created it using prefixes of reverse-sorted values and thought I could change it to postfixes of sorted, but actually couldn't because I'm then tailing... reverted :)

Comment: Yes, now border test case  `[179, 89, 59, 44, 35, 29], 180, 3` correctly gives 0. And any increment of four last values will yield 1

Comment: Saved a couple of bytes by noticing I don't actually need each prefix, but only the last value of each prefix. Also flipped around `0` and `1` to save a byte

Comment: Added test cases, for convenience. Can you please explain how does that code work? :) I dont know Jelly..

Comment: Yeah, now I've finished golfing I'm writing an explanation.

Comment: Elegant solution, but strange, output is 1 now again. Even for [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] output is 1

Comment: It now "prints `0` if the peer is rewarded and `1` if not". (i.e. `0` is "yes"). It saves 1 byte :)

Comment: I think yours is to be accepted! You were the first to post it, given a great explanation, a port to python, and had most influence to many's other answers. Also its still shortest. Well done, great job!

Comment: Btw, are you familar with hilbert curve? Could you [help me](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/177443/hilbertize-an-image) to find efficient algorithm to converting 2D image to 1D representation with spatial locality property?

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
{Rƶ.ssè›ß
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/OujYNr3i4sMrHjXsOjz///9oQwMDHVMDHXNzHSMjHUMTHRPTWC5jLkMLAwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9o4Pa/OujYNr3i4sMrHjXsOjz/v87/aAMdBTMghlJgZiyXMZehhQFXtKG5pY6CBRCbArGJiY6CsSkQ45M301EwsoTLGxuAlKNjhHYDIN8UiM3NgdqMdBQMgUaYmMLlLS2BxoIJkPkQRxJwHJLlYHlLA5zy6A4zsiTCcSZQeQA).

Port of [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178444/52210), so also takes the inputs `x T M` and outputs `0` for `"yes"` and `1` for `"no"`. If this is not allowed, and it should be inverted, a trailing `_` can be added.

**Explanation:**

```python
{           # Sort the (implicit) input `x`
            #  i.e. `x`=[100,50,77,22,14,45] → [14,22,45,50,77,100]
 R          # Reverse it
            #  i.e. [14,22,45,50,77,100] → [100,77,50,45,22,14]
  ƶ         # Multiply it by it's 1-indexed range
            #  i.e. [100,77,50,45,22,14] → [100,154,150,180,110,84]
   .s       # Get all the suffices of this list
            #  i.e. [100,154,150,180,110,84]
            #   → [[84],[110,84],[180,110,84],[150,180,110,84],[100,154,150,180,110,84]]
     s      # Swap to take the (implicit) input `T`
      è     # Get the prefix at index `T`
            #  i.e. [[84],[110,84],[180,110,84],[150,180,110,84],[100,154,150,180,110,84]]
            #   and `T=3` → [150,180,110,84]
       ›    # Check for each list-value if the (implicit) input `M` is larger than it
            #  i.e. [150,180,110,84] and `M`=180 → [1,0,1,1]
        ß   # And pop and push the minimum value in the list (which is output implicitly)
            #  i.e. [1,0,1,1] → 0
```

---

Alternative for `.ssè`:

```python
sG¦}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/OujYtmL3Q8tqHzXsOjz///9oQwMDHVMDHXNzHSMjHUMTHRPTWC5jLkMLAwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9o4Pa/OujYtmL3Q8tqHzXsOjz/v87/aAMdBTMghlJgZiyXMZehhQFXtKG5pY6CBRCbArGJiY6CsSkQ45M301EwsoTLGxuAlKNjhHYDIN8UiM3NgdqMdBQMgUaYmMLlLS2BxoIJkPkQRxJwHJLlYHlLA5zy6A4zsiTCcSZQeQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
s       # Swap to take the (implicit) input `T`
 G }    # Loop `T-1` times:
  ¦     #  Remove the first item from the list that many times
        #   i.e. [100,154,150,180,110,84] and `T=3` → [150,180,110,84]
```

Comment: I didn't stated on "how should you map output", just that it have to be boolean (to has only 2 states). So yes, definetely you may use 0 for "yes" and 1 for "no" :)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc) with flag `/u:System.Linq.Enumerable`, 69 bytes

```cs
(n,x,t,m)=>Range(0,n-m+1).Where(b=>x.Count(a=>a>=t/(b+m))>=b+m).Any()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY4xT8MwEIV3foVHW726SdOmNWBLCMHEBEMHxJBEFliqzyFxRCvEX8e4TStVDKi00r3zG97nd1U7rFoT7jusrg16iHp@gZ2D0rmlqmWgCCvwYJlUjwW@apoADu0gZXzxphtNS6lW/NZ16GkhVaGkH9FyYBlTcvPwG1xTFq4uFo3x@sGgpjXNgaD@INvCTyEEkO2aRiX9fAFJ59FkjP2BxkDeA/neHgems1g131VOJjE@BTIWZ8DZyc35P5tFctrZ2SZxoLE4/urfbK9DNny72huHbRh1l0/r1mvL40/v/A47q5uiXOof)

```cs
// Takes in 4 parameters as input
(n,x,t,m)=>
// Create a new array with the length of all the numbers from m to n, inclusive
Range(0,n-m+1)
// And filter the results by
.Where((_,b)=>
// If the number of people that invested more than the total amount divided by the index plus m
x.Count(a=>a>=t/(b+m))
// Is greater than the index plus m
>= b+m)
// And check if there is at least one value in the filtered IEnumerable<int>, and if there is, return true
.Any()
```

## Without any flags, 73 bytes

```cs
(n,x,t,m)=>new int[n-m+1].Where((_,b)=>x.Count(a=>a>=t/(b+m))>=b+m).Any()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY5RC4IwFIXf@xV73PBmmmaO2iCCnnr3ISRSBg1yRk4qot9uMw2khyiDne3AznfPTYthWshqVap0LpUGo00MrYMkzw/8yCqs4AIaMsK4EmdUh9Qws9zYjvbiJDDeQmL@LvYyL5XGO8Z3nOkRTqyMEM7qx16oKybVbBCdpBZrqQQ@4gDQa158o5QCel4TI6c5d0BuaIxHyAfUBIIGCF72O9CdmqqwrfR9E58AGtM/YK93c/BjM3X6re3ViY7G9Put39lGXbZ6AA)

Comment: I thought of that, and stated in the description that N>=1, and M<=N So you may shorten your solution a bit :)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```
(x,t,m,n)=>x.sort((a,b)=>a-b).some(i=>i*n-->=t&n>=m)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##DchNDsIgEEDhPadgZQYzNFD74wYuYlzQSg2mDKYQ09sji7f43sf9XF6P8C2S0svXzVQ4sWBEEsaeXU5HAXC4NDm5iDaih2BsuJKU1pQLWRNFXRPltPtuT2/YgD20UsjH1jwj73vkekA@jE9k@q6Q3ZBNTIj6Bw)

Comment: Also 35-40% more performant that 72-byted solution. Lovely code, felt like its ready to be embedded in production MLM-related web projects :^)

Comment: Just noticed. Test case #2 `[0, 60, 0, 60, 60, 0], 180, 3 -> true` seems to be [not working!](https://tio.run/##nY7BDoIwDIbvPsVOZjMFUWCyw3gDL8ab8TBxmBnYDEzC2@MUTdSDikn/pmv77e9RNKLOKnWynjZ72eW8wy1YKEETnrZ@bSqLsYCdewlvR1yjlFjxVE2056XcjnXKS9JNpyuZSdXIGil9OluXUW6qUljUbrawhiUgPcqMrk0h/cIccI43jDFAtxQ7BX1sAc0SV4SAKCHviBvQfpE@ys/AbOG@Tu4WUeTWYkBz9gcUDnaiPzqxYNh54XXypDn7ft070@uV6S4) 72 byted bersion handles it ok. Bug or feature?)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 79 bytes

```
\d+
*
O^`_+(?=.*])
_+(?=.*])(?<=(\W+_+)+)
$#1*$&
+`\W+_+(.*_)_$
$1
(_+).*], \1,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hU1NC4JAEL3PrxDaYr8Q11VzIPHYsWMHzd2gDl06RP9/m7REJAzmzTzeezPzuD5v97MJa773ob0okHDovFO8rmJ5EjAyXu8q3h6VU0IJYCsj2QaU7xUeSyccA2aAk09xHbVGh9Agoo76lhOSocg1JRELDfViUIsvnbhmS0vlZznLSMt1lOK/hF2@Ufy6gcnCF/seE6Q4ezIPDBgDLw) Takes input in the format `[x], T, M`. Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\d+
*
```

Convert to unary.

```
O^`_+(?=.*])
```

Sort `[x]` in descending order.

```
_+(?=.*])(?<=(\W+_+)+)
$#1*$&
```

Multiply each element of `[x]` by its index.

```
+`\W+_+(.*_)_$
$1
```

Delete the first `M-1` elements of `[x]`.

```
(_+).*], \1,
```

Test whether any remaining element of `[x]` is greater or equal to `T`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>46 33</s> 29 bytes

```perl6
{$^b>all $^a.sort Z*[...] @_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1olLskuMSdHQSUuUa84v6hEIUorWk9PL1bBIb72f3FipYJ9mka0paWljgKYMAViAwiK1VEwtAAyzHSMNXWUFHTtFAyUrLlgWkASEIVmMCamBkMkDYbmQKMtoFaYmOgoGJvqKBhZ4rcFqyZjkm0yw24ThiZLA9KcZ2wAcg0CG1lidx0@PRCM1XH/AQ)

Anonymous code blocks that takes input in the form `list, amount, length of list, minimum amount of investors` and returns a truthy/falsey `all` Junction, where truthy is failed and falsey is success.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                           }  # Anonymous code block
     all                       # Are all of
         $^a.sort                # The sorted list
                  Z*             # Zip multiplied by
                     [...] @_    # The range from length of list to the minimum amount
 $^b>                          # Not smaller than the given amount?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

Input taken in the order `T`, `N`, `x[]`, `M`
Output is `0` for peer reward and `1` if not

```
Ÿs{*›W
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6I7iaq1HDbvC//835jLjijY0t9RRsABiUyA2MdFRMDbVUTCyjOUytDAAAA)
or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9o4Pb/6I7iaq1HDbvC/@vE/DfmMuOKNtBRMANiKAVmxnIZWhhwgWUNzS11FCyA2BSITUx0FIxNgRi/CjMdBSNLJBXGBiAt6BjZCAOgiCkQm5sDtRrpKBgCjTExRVJhaQk0HEyAbIE4l6AzURwBVmFpgEcFuhONLIlypglYBQA)

**Explanation**

```
Ÿ        # push the range [N ... T]
 s{      # push the list x[] sorted ascending
   *     # elementwise multiplication (crops to shortest list)
    ›    # for each element, check if M is greater than it
     W   # push min of the result
         # output implicitly
```

Comment: Nice trick of using `*` with the range to implicitly crop the list!

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>129</s>, 89 bytes

EDIT:  Thanks to Kevin Cruijssen for golfing off 40 bytes while explaining the mechanics as to why!

```cs
(n,q,t,m)=>{int c=0,j;for(;m<=n&c<1;c=c<m++?0:1)for(j=n;j-->0;)c+=q[j]<t/m?0:1;return c;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZDPS8MwFMfv/SseO0hDs9nuR7eaZh4Eb4IwwcPcoYvdaGkTl6SKjP3t9XWdIB7EQ0vyfXm8Rz58@QozFEqndWUyuYfVp7FpyRxRJMbAo1Z7nZRHB@Ct2haZAGMTi8@7yl7hIcmkS5olwH0lRZxJS2FXqMSuN5eGwnmIZQlb4LUr6YFaWhK@POIQBPdpznZKu6yMubwSccAEF3Hpebf@TUCaTc4ly4fDpc@I8PhhnW9ie102a6ZTW2kJgp1q5rTeR3dKGlWko2ed2dTduiEFmX5cfIUbOEZRROFcZii/vScKwQKbCRk9qZXVGIZLvMGLHJD/k/F/2PLC77YTbjBHo4uL4ekUaTMK46g/9qQv32G3viO/l0wmDeCHxlFnkfxGt@omEb9JAzWfo@UxIqdNMj2yZ3@ynROe@gs)

Comment: [106 bytes](https://tinyurl.com/y9t7vsn2) Some of the things I've changed: Removed the input `n` since you don't use it anywhere; removed `k` since you can use `m` itself; added a variable `l` for `q.Length` since you use it twice; combined the variables `int c=0,l=q.Length,j;` so you don't need the additional `var`; removed the unnecessary brackets by putting everything in the for-loop body; changed the `c>=k` check to `c<k`; and changed the `if(c>0)break;` to `m=c>0?l+1:m;`, since the loop stops if `m<=l`, changing `m` to `l+1` saves a byte over `break` (and it also saves on 2 brackets). :)

Comment: If you haven't seen it yet, [Tips for golfing in C#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c) and [Tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) might be interesting to read, through.

Comment: [89 bytes](https://tinyurl.com/y9vufswg) Some additions to the golfs in my first comment. The `m=c>0?l+1:m` can be removed completely and a `&c<1` check can be added to the loop instead. And by taking the input `n` again, you don't need the `q.Length` anymore but can use `n` instead.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 72 bytes

#### Code

```javascript
(x,T,M)=>x.sort(t=(d,e)=>e-d).map((s,i)=>s*i+s).slice(M-1).sort(t)[0]>=T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lU5LCoMwEN33FFkmbfx/ahZ6AzfFnbgQjSVFjZhUvL2N1YK4aCvMG2aG95lHPuSi6FkntZaXdKrCCY44wTEKo1EXvJdQhrDEVO1UK5He5B2EAjO1izO7CKSLmhUUxpqFVj5KzSwKk8kwbrSgbKACsLZ7StVBxfsml2BMsznkVPBW8JrqNb/DCqaEEAzezVMwl8owsAI1OAjt@erqLyz/M35hW1dlGqzmrqs4HgY2OapwjmX4/2QQ88BXznzewCY/ntoLFmwE0ws)

Accepts input in format (x[],T,M)

#### Explanation

```javascript
x.sort(t=(d,e)=>e-d)     \\sort numbers in reverse numerical order
.map((s,i)=>s*i+s)       \\Multiply each number in array by position(1 indexed) in array
.slice(M-1)              \\Remove the first M-1 elements (at least M people)
.sort(t)[0]              \\Get the maximum value in the array
>=T                      \\True if the maximum value is >= the threshold
```

Comment: [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##lU7LDoIwELz7FT2ZVivIQ6QH/AMuxhvhQGAxNUoJrYa/x0U0IRxUks7udjIzu5fskem8kbXZVKqArow62vITj1l0aC2tGkNpwQF/sCkYEjegVHOJxHotD1G81CtsJ9bZ9hFykA/QRFb13WAlpWpumSFtkvaRi1xVWl3BuqozLWkihODkVXaI7fBSTpwQB4@xqR7ZYFAFn/GL2tljaPgO933U7DhxxVyHN29H8M8OsZ1xldfTI7jix1FTw4CRoXsC)?

Comment: (Or [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##lU7LDoIwELz7FT22Unkq0gT8Ay6GG@FAYDE1SAlFgon/jkU0IR5Ukp3N7mRmds9pl8qs4XW7qUQOQxEMuKcRDUlw6HUpmhbjnILaYJMTHTpobhhLyhWjadwP73LN/YgMhnGEDHgHEvGqvraqo0I0l7RFfZyMiatMVFKUoJfihAscM8YoeradgjlVQpHlqcEh5FOvWHdSue/xi9raq1DvFb7dKs2OIpstdTjLbrj/3GDmgq@ckZ7BZj@e@jRMmBmGBw) if the meaning of the Boolean value can be inverted.)

Comment: @Arnauld, [52 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178452/58974) ;)

Comment: (By the way, I came up with my solution independently of your comment, in case you were wondering - it's a port of my Japt solution. On mobile so can't see timestamps properly to tell who posted first.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 136 bytes

Just tests the conditions to make sure they are met. 1 if the reward is given, 0 if not.

```python
lambda N,x,T,M:(sum(x)>=T)*(M<=N)*any(any(all(j>=T/k for j in i)for i in combinations(x,k))for k in range(M,N+1))
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZJNbsIwEIXX5BQjdWOnlpofCBg1vUFYVOwoC0NMa4ht5LhqOH1qB1pKCRKSnzWa@fT05PH@YD@0StuSW26kUPyVfzFT5m9txeSqZDAjDZmTYorqT4ka/JLPcYiK53yGQ6YOqFNVoa0bPO1gow1sQSgQ2JfCl2stV0IxK7SqUUN2uBvt/Mgw9c5RQWaPMcbBxmgJwuWwWlc1CLnXxoat5bVds5rXkMMiGKCMwIJSSqC7Rk7R8SwJxBNXpJjAA0Qn1DWyI5D9lJdgfALjsbOanCyHQzceEUhov2svnN7tnF07X8A0ui9G6jt/lNDrFLfYo26EiHwAp/HYmSaOGfowN96iFx6d4c54GQR@736bfvW/W50Gg70RyqJ/XxCFHsG4/QY)

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, <s>16</s> <s>14</s> <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
ñ í*WõX)d¨V
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8SDtKlf1WClkqFY=&input=WzEwMCwgNTAsIDc3LCAyMiwgMTQsIDQ1XQoxODAKMwo2)

```
ñ í*WõX)d¨V
                  :Implicit input of array U=x and integers V=T, W=M & X=N
ñ                 :Sort U
  í               :Interleave with
    WõX           :  Range [W,X]
   *              :  And reduce each pair of elements by multiplication
       )          :End interleaving
        d         :Any
         ¨V       :  Greater than or equal to V
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org),  <s>71</s>  65 bytes

```python
lambda x,T,M:all(i*v<T for i,v in enumerate(sorted(x)[-M::-1],M))
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDLCsIwEEX3fsXsksgU@rYp6h905067iDTVQG0lraJfX9NUQUSlIXcyj8MdyPneHZva78vVrq/EaV8IuOEGs1RUFVXz63IDZaNB4RVUDbK@nKQWnaRtoztZ0BvbOlmaOl6OGWP9gAp9aAeWzsAeuuWcI9gQGbnjzRG8xCQBsxwazlTxOI1f6RfKWxiT5GkWhmYWIfh8KhlM84z/eXJ3wvZgKN/k8x/LP8FRHyBL7XPWqu7sFyMQZ01MdAmoEko6H7oMZNVKIB7pHw)**

An unnamed function; port of my Jelly answer. As such "yes" is `False` and "no" is `True`. Here, however, we discard test-cases as a part of the reversal and take advantage of the ability to initiate the `enumerate` count to `M`. (`min` would also work in place of `all`)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>43</s> 42 bytes

*-1 bytes by implementing the approach even more closely*

```r
function(N,x,S,M)min(sort(x,T)[M:N]*M:N<S)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBBC4JAEIXP7a9Y6LIbc9h1tdxogw51Sg9Zp@gQgiCYihpsv95GLfPQMO9d3seDmapNTJs887hJi5yFYCGCgD/SnNVF1TALZ34N1uFtgbaJeGuliZnWGmhvHkoMy2dzKqnZ0sPuGO2JdRCUK8z9D@e6QJWH6lHRoefTBUmFpBJd8JOjv@C00/1DDuIUZ9pKQrMkgVEkMtIXhNT3ssxeLEtrvEqCdcAqsC6H8XjLk/EBvH0D)

Simple R implementation of Jonathan's Jelly approach. I tried a bunch of variations but this pips the best I could think of by a few bytes.

1 implies failure, 0 implies success.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 91 (or 89?) bytes

```java
(N,x,T,M)->{int c=0,j;for(;M<=N&c<1;c=c<M++?0:1)for(j=N;j-->0;)c+=x[j]<T/M?0:1;return c;}
```

Port of [*@Destroigo*'s C# .NET answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178477/52210) (after I golfed it some more), so make sure to upvote him!

Takes inputs `N,x,T,M` and outputs `true`/`false` for `"yes"`/`"no"` respectively.

Since the challenge specifically asks for `boolean` results, I can't return the `1`/`0` as is, since those aren't [valid truthy/falsey values](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/52210) in Java. If any two distinct output values for `"yes"`/`"no"` is valid for this challenge instead, the `>0` in the return can be dropped to save two bytes, in which case it'll return `1`/`0` for `"yes"`/`"no"` respectively.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##rVHBcoIwEL37FXvqwBg0KKAI2FtvcJGb4yFGbKEYHAhWx@Hb6Qa91Eut9fA2ZN7y9m1exg7MyDafLc9ZVUHIUnHuAaRCJuWW8QQidQVYF0WeMAFcQwoignW5gqM6Ie5qqHvY2fSwVJLJlEMEAgJotYgcSUxC3ZifVSMPKMm8bVFqXugH0Qv3TY8H3A/7/Vc6M3XFZEHkZYYxp57O@8Fxma38eBgq2isTWZdoBLmmVSP39TrHadehhyLdwA7X0BayTMU7umT6ZYfhEOKylh@nWXddnCqZ7AZFLQd77JS50MSAaw4RyRd0@50pAQdxPbrPhphTSsZ6t@1dIubEJTBF2AjLIjC2EU8RcgiM3L8LjakycIsHDFH80UZMJmhkRMBEU5b9u9CVwUDeWF4l9wfiurh6V9QbXKJ5ViSPvGQn5NL/C93GMXKfGYn1Q6jpNe03)

**Explanation:**

```java
(N,x,T,M)->{           // Method with the four parameters and boolean return-type
  int c=0,             //  Count integer, starting at 0
      j;               //  Temp index integer
  for(;M<=N            //  Loop as long as `M` is smaller than or equal to `N`
       &c<1            //  and `c` is not 1 yet:
      ;                //    After every iteration:
       c=c<M++?        //     If `M` is smaller than `c`:
                       //     (and increase `M` by 1 afterwards with `M++`)
          0            //      Set `c` to 0
         :             //     Else:
          1)           //      Set `c` to 1
    for(j=N;j-->0;)    //   Inner loop `j` in the range (`N`,0]:
       c+=             //    Increase the counter `c` by:
          x[j]         //     If the `j`'th value in `x`
              <T/M?    //     is smaller than `T` divided by `M`:
                   0   //      Leave the counter `c` unchanged by adding 0
                  :    //     Else:
                   1;  //      Increase the counter `c` by 1
  return c>0;}         //  Return whether the counter `c` is 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 66 bytes

```cs
(n,x,t,m)=>Enumerable.Range(m,n-m+1).Any(k=>x.Count(y=>y>=t/k)>=k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVLBSsNAEL3nK4biYRensW3a2FB3oYiePFnBQ@ghjRsNTTaw3WBDyLfHTdJKrEUp7Oy8nX1vZg4v3A3DXVw/5jK8i6XGNxHGaZD46yPCprrJsoRDBKwmEveoMaWMP8g8FSrYJMJ@DuS7ICnKYXo9pvZSFmTL@N6@z3KpScF4wZm@2VLOtrReWFGmRBB@EGJ6g0QwyV/DvgWgu5QiNFNBUfMEKT79dWkRFw/Q8zyE9pqZGHWnQhjPDXAQoiDZCYo9ham7Hc89wh5fq/wnfXxr@s4P/adTQ5ohTLw/R5zVOBeOcU/GnJd4o4s2c5qPXky8k8X@l3Txa7GKQmkBvKpYi6dYCnI1KFUFjEMZNWaxVyIRYWsCcrAULaj9ki2VCgpC8bvauKoa0IVV1V8)

Inspired by @EmbodimentOfIgnorance's answer.

I've mentioned this before, but C# 8 has a range literal which could make this answer something like this:

```cs
(n,x,t,m)=>[m..n-m+1].Any(k=>x.Count(y=>y>=t/k)>=k)
```

I saw a link to [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io) with an example, but I wasn't able to get it to work myself.

One thing I changed was the `x` and `t` values are decimals. This handles the case where `t` is not divisible by `k` a little better.